# What does it mean by Marginal Probability?

Tags: random-variables, marginal-distribution

Suppose, we have the following distribution for a number of subscribers of HBO Network:

\begin{matrix}
 \text{TV-Show/Sex}     & \text{Male} & \text{Female} & \text{Sum}\\
 \text{Game-of-Throne} & 0.16 & 0.24 & 0.40\\
 \text{West-world}     & 0.20 & 0.05 & 0.25\\
 \text{Others}         & 0.10 & 0.25 & 0.35\\
 \text{Sum}            & 0.46 & 0.54 & 1
 \end{matrix}

I understand that 46% of the viewers are Males.

But, is $0.46$ a marginal distribution of *(Sex=Male)* w.r.t. *TV-Show*, or, is it a marginal distribution of *TV-Show* w.r.t. *(Sex=Male)*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never encountered one talking about marginal distribution of $X$ with respect to an event or vice versa. You have two random variables TV-show and Sex, and is 0.46 a probability of an event with respect to the marginal distribution of Sex. In other words; it is the marginal probability that a subscriber is male.